# Not able to add Intent to Google Maps inside ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I have a code list whose items are references to something and have an address. I need to make it such that when any item of that list is clicked, then Google Maps Navigation should be launched corresponding to the address for the rowitem. Btw the address won't be visible within the row, The address is the object from which the row information is taken. I have tried the code :-

```
rowview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(context,);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Yeah Boy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LatLng tmp = objects.get(position).location;
            String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()+"&daddr="+tmp.latitude+","+tmp.longitude;  
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rowview;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I'm having this error :-

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u tried after adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag with intent ?

Comment: Yes I did, then it is marked as an error.

Comment: which error u are getting when adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag ?

Comment: The constructor Intent(int, Uri) is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it as :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String uri = "Your URI String ";
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
                 "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Constructor Intent(int, Uri) is undefined

Set the flag using `setFlag` method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what context is in the variable "context".

If your code is contained within an activity, instead of "context" try

ActivityClass.this.startActivity(intent);